# NLog - Can a FallbackGroup wrapper contain another FallbackGroup wrapper?

Tags: c#, winforms, nlog

In NLog ... can a FallbackGroup wrapper contain another FallbackGroup wrapper?  That is I want a cascade effect to handle if my 1st target (writing to a Database) fails, then my 2nd target will be to write to both a file and send an email.
And what config settings are needed to implement this structure (so that NLog handles encountered exceptions [ex. writing to the database failure] properly)?

Thanks for your time and any suggestions you offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want fallback to write to two targets then you can combine it with SplitGroup:

```
<target xsi:type="FallbackGroup" 
        name="db_fallback"
        returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">
    <target xsi:type="Database" name="db" />
    <target xsi:type="SplitGroup" name="split_db_fallback">
        <target xsi:type="file" name="file_db_fallback" />
        <target xsi:type="mail" name="mail_db_fallback" />
    </target>
</target>
```

See also https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/SplitGroup-target

Comment: I look forward to using this.  AWESOME.